# Creating an oracle table with auto increment feature

Tags: oracle

How to create an oracle table with an auto increment column such that whenever exsisiting value is getting inserted it should increment the counter otherwise it should insert a new count

For instance if I have a column with phone number and status
There should be an another column named counter on which auto increment feature will be present

Whenever exsiting phonenumber is inserted again then counter must be increment and if a new value is inserted then counter should add a new initial value for that number

Comment: so every phone number has its own counter?

Comment: Yes. If the same phonenumber is getting inserted again then only counter should increment

Comment: Thanks for ur response.  In the same example that you have given is it possible to get max of emp_id for each group of department id

Comment: You need to explain more about how you want the data to look and why you want to do this. You can easily count the number of occurrences of a number.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want to insert the data. If you are going to be inserting many rows at the same time then try a `MERGE`statement. 
Join with the phone number, if found increment the counter column value else set the counter to 1.

If you are going to be inserting one row at a time then this is best done in the code that performs an insert.

**EDIT:** I did not think this through. Now that I am, I think it is unnecessary to use a counter column. 
If you are going to insert phone numbers multiple times anyway, why don't you simply count each phone number? It doesn't have to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a table like that.

You can, however, add your own logic into the place where you INSERT new rows - eg, it's not in the table itself. You can also go the route of a `TRIGGER`.

Additionally, you may wish to simply have your ID be a unique GUID that gets generated and create this duplicate counter whenever it is necessary, using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` like `EMP_ID` in this example from the [oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm):

```
SELECT department_id, last_name, employee_id, ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY employee_id) AS emp_id
   FROM employees;

DEPARTMENT_ID LAST_NAME                 EMPLOYEE_ID     EMP_ID
------------- ------------------------- ----------- ----------
           10 Whalen                            200          1
           20 Hartstein                         201          1
           20 Fay                               202          2
           30 Raphaely                          114          1
           30 Khoo                              115          2
           30 Baida                             116          3
           30 Tobias                            117          4
           30 Himuro                            118          5
           30 Colmenares                        119          6
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is it possible to get maximum of emp_id for each department I'd instead of getting all emp if for each departments

Comment: `SELECT Department, MAX(emp_id) as Maximum FROM employees GROUP BY Department`

Answer (score -1):

For Auto Increment You can create a sequence as below.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE name_of_sequence
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1;
```

For the second part of your query you can   define a trigger that automatically populates the primary key value using above  sequence

Comment: That is not what the OP is asking. The question was for a counter column. Not a primary key.

Comment: When Insertion is to be done in a new Column  Whenever exsiting phonenumber is inserted again then counter /sequence can be incremented and inserted in a new Column

Comment: Isn't that same as counting the number of times a phone number is present? And how to check if the phone number is already present?

Comment: OP is basically asking for an id for every set of duplicates.

Comment: before insertion you can check if the phone no is inserted or not inside the logic .If it is present you can execute the sequence or auto increment value ,i hope it should clear your doubt.

Comment: @nitin.sharma0180 yes I get that. What I'm saying is its moot. If you have 9876543210 3 times, you can just count it instead of storing 3 in a counter column.